# Python callback issue with GPIO on raspberry

Tags: python, callback, raspberry-pi

I'm an absolute python newbie and this is my first raspberry project. I try to build a simple music player in which every input button loads a different album (8 albums) and 3 buttons to control playback (next, pause, last).

To load the music I use a USB drive which, as soon as it is connected automatically triggers the copy process.

The buttons are debounced with a callback function. Everything works great, except that after new music is loaded with the USB drive the buttons don't work anymore.

Most likely it is a simple programming issue which I - as a beginner - just don't see.

This is the code to work with two buttons:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import os 
import pyudev 
from time import sleep 
from mpd import MPDClient 
from socket import error as SocketError 

# Configure MPD connection settings 
HOST = 'localhost' 
PORT = '6600' 
CON_ID = {'host':HOST, 'port':PORT} 

#Configure Buttons 
Button1 = 25 
Button2 = 24 


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
GPIO.setup(Button1, GPIO.IN) 
GPIO.setup(Button2, GPIO.IN) 


client = MPDClient() 

#Function to check if USB is connected 
def checkForUSBDevice(name): 
        res = "" 
        context = pyudev.Context() 
        for device in context.list_devices(subsystem='block', DEVTYPE='partition'): 
                if device.get('ID_FS_LABEL') == name: 
                        res = device.device_node 
        return res 

#Function to load music from USB         
def loadMusic(client, con_id, device): 
        os.system("mount "+device+" /music/usb") 
        os.system("/etc/init.d/mpd stop") 
        os.system("rm -r /music/mp3/*") 
        os.system("cp -r /music/usb/* /music/mp3/") 
        os.system("umount /music/usb") 
        os.system("rm /music/mpd/tag_cache") 
        os.system("/etc/init.d/mpd start") 
        os.system("mpc clear") 
        os.system("mpc ls | mpc add") 
        os.system("/etc/init.d/mpd restart") 

#Function to connect to MPD 
def mpdConnect(client, con_id): 
        try: 
                client.connect(**con_id) 
        except SocketError: 
                return False 
        return True 

#Function to load an Album 
def loadAlbum(number): 
    mpdConnect(client, CON_ID)   
    if client.status()["state"] == "play" or client.status()["state"] == "pause": client.stop()  
    os.system("mpc clear") 
    os.system("mpc ls "+str(number)+" | mpc add") 
    client.play() 
    client.disconnect() 



#Callback Function 
def buttonPressed(channel): 
    if channel == Button1: 
        print('Button 1 HIT') 
        loadAlbum(1) 
    elif channel == Button2: 
        print('Button 2 HIT') 
        loadAlbum(2) 


def main(): 
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Button1, GPIO.RISING, callback=buttonPressed, bouncetime=200) 
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Button2, GPIO.RISING, callback=buttonPressed, bouncetime=200) 

    # This function just creates an endless loop which does 
    # nothing, in order for the button detection to work  
    try: 
        flag = 0 
        while flag == 0: 
            device = checkForUSBDevice("MUSIC") # MUSIC is the name of my thumb drive  
            if flag == 1: 
                flag = 0 
            else: 
                flag = 0 

            if device != "":  
            # USB thumb drive has been inserted, new music will be copied  
                print('USB erkannt, Musik wird kopiert.', device) 
                loadMusic(client, CON_ID, device)   
                print('Musik wurde kopiert, USB kann entfernt werden!', device) 
                while checkForUSBDevice("MUSIC") == device: 
                    sleep(1.0) 
                print('USB wurde entfernt.') 
                loadAlbum(1) 

    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        GPIO.cleanup()  



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Hope anyone can help me on this?

Matthias

Comment: It's difficult to tell because there are indentation errors in your code in the lines following `while flag == 0:` (line 150 in your full source). The code as posted should raise a `SyntaxError` exception. You should post the actual source. Possibly the problem is with that `while` loop.

Comment: I tried to fix the indentation as mentioned - but still no luck. I don't get any SytaxnError exception. All works fine, the music starts playing after copying from the USB. But the buttons still don't work after unplugging the USB drive. What do you mean by "You should post the actual source"? This is all I have. (I updated the code in the post and on the Dropbox). Thanks so far

Comment: @matto The best way to describe the question is to provide short working piece of code. You are almost there, just adding few imports would clarify, what of GPIO libraries you use. Providing the code over dropbox is not recommended as the code shall remain part of the question after the link will stop working. Making the working code sample short takes some work, but often leads either to direct solution, or to faster answer.

Comment: Thank you for your support and advising me. I have shortened the code to a "two button" version and pasted it into the question.  Now it should be everything relevant there.  Hope anyone can help!

Comment: What do you mean by "the buttons don't work anymore"? Is the callback function still called? Is the debug message for the corresponding button printed? You need to try and determine whether the problem is with the event handling, or whether it is something else to do with the loading and playing of the music files.

Comment: The debug message for the corresponding button is NOT printed. There is just no reaction when pressing a button, no music loaded, no message. I doubt that the issue is with loading the music files since the music starts playing after the USB is unplugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what did the trick for me. Probably it's not the best solution but it seams to do the trick. 
Only the main function was changed. Changes are highlighted at the beginning of the line with a comment.

```
def main():  
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Button1, GPIO.RISING, callback=buttonPressed, bouncetime=200)  
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Button2, GPIO.RISING, callback=buttonPressed, bouncetime=200)  

    # This function just creates an endless loop which does  
    # nothing, in order for the button detection to work   
    try:  
        flag = 0  
        while flag == 0:  
            device = checkForUSBDevice("MUSIC") # MUSIC is the name of my thumb drive   
            if flag == 1:  
                flag = 0  
            else:  
                flag = 0  

            if device != "":   
            # USB thumb drive has been inserted, new music will be copied   
                print('USB erkannt, Musik wird kopiert.', device) 

# Stop the callback before loading the files from the USB:  
                GPIO.remove_event_detect(Button1) 
                GPIO.remove_event_detect(Button2) 

                loadMusic(client, CON_ID, device)    
                print('Musik wurde kopiert, USB kann entfernt werden!', device)  
                while checkForUSBDevice("MUSIC") == device:  
                    sleep(1.0)  
                print('USB wurde entfernt.')  
                loadAlbum(1)  

# Recall the main function 
                main() 

    except KeyboardInterrupt:  
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the buttons dont work any more is because you are still in the callback function - so it cant get triggered again.  The solution is to use the callback function to simply set a flag and have the main waiting loop detect the flag and do the playing.  But note that playing is probably blocking so that the main loop will also have stopped for the duration.